# IPTables is blocking all outgoing traffic to http even though I allowed it

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I am using the following code to allow DNS requests, and outgoing traffic to port `443`, `22` and `80`

However, all the traffic to port `443` and `80` is blocked for some reason

```
# Allowing DNS lookups (tcp, udp port 53) to server '8.8.8.8'
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 8.8.8.8 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 8.8.8.8 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allowing DNS lookups (tcp, udp port 53) to server '127.0.0.53'
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 127.0.0.53 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s 127.0.0.53 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.53 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.53 --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


 # allow all and everything on localhost
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allowing new and established incoming connections to port 22, 80, 443
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow all outgoing connections to port 22
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing icmp connections (pings,...)
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections to port 123 (ntp syncs)
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j LOG -m limit --limit 12/min --log-level 4 --log-prefix IP INPUT drop:
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG -m limit --limit 12/min --log-level 4 --log-prefix IP OUTPUT drop:
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

 # Set default policy to 'DROP'
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD DROP
/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

I can see following in syslog,

```
Sep 28 08:17:06 ip-172-31-57-142 kernel: [  486.605568] IP OUTPUT drop: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=172.31.57.142 DST=172.217.7.206 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=30718 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37026 DPT=443 WINDOW=62727 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 28 08:17:07 ip-172-31-57-142 kernel: [  487.617296] IP OUTPUT drop: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=172.31.57.142 DST=172.217.7.206 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=30719 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=37026 DPT=443 WINDOW=62727 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at just one part of this, where you want to allow outbound connections for ssh on port tcp/22

```
# Allowing new and established incoming connections to port 22, 80, 443
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow all outgoing connections to port 22
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The first pair of rules does not do what the comment says. The second pair should work but is over generous. All four rules are *nearly* correct, but end up not being sufficiently correct. Instead, just keep it simple

```
# Allow outgoing connections to port tcp/22
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow return traffic for established connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: can you please elaborate why my rules are not correct

Comment: I've reviewed the rules with an updated answer. Rules as follows... 1. Allows traffic in to _your_ ports 22, 80, 443,, but you seemed to imply you wanted only outgoing traffic to these ports. 2. Allows established traffic back out from your ports 22, 80, 443